# BigQuery detailed charges just shows how much data was analyzed

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to find out what is causing my BigQuery bill to be so high but when I click `View Detailed Charges` on Google Cloud I just get how much data was analyzed and how much it costs. Is there a place where I can view a detailed breakdown of what jobs cost so much and what is causing the bill to get so large?

Comment: It sounds like you would be interested in [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a place where I can view a detailed breakdown of what jobs cost so much and what is causing the bill to get so large?

You should be able to use [Jobs.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list) API to lists all jobs that you started in the specified project. Job information is available for a six month period after creation. The job list is sorted in reverse chronological order, by job creation time. Requires the Can View project role, or the Is Owner project role if you set the allUsers property

You actually can even make it without any coding - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list#try-it

Collect all you jobs info and analyse it as you wish

For the long term solution - you can either automate above process or use [BigQuery Monitoring using Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring)

Comment: Is there a way I can simply see how much bigquery billed me?

Comment: you should make some simple efforts for this  - which I tried to outlined in my answer :o)

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase. I see it's telling me how many bytes I was billed but is there an easy way to just calculate how much it actually costed. I still struggle with the math on the BigQuery billing scheme.

Comment: billing bytes multiply by billing tier and multiple by $5.00 per 1TB

Comment: So what would the cost of a query that billed `10485760` bytes at billing tier 1 be? Free?

Comment: good point - minimum charge is for 10MB. so even if you query 1 BT - you will be charged for 10MB. that why you should use billing bytes vs, just processed bytes

Comment: This is why I'm still confused. I'm aware 1tb is $5 standard but I'm still not sure how I can calculate the price of just a single query that processes say 200mb.

Comment: cost of such query for tier 1 is 5*200/1024/1024 = $0.000953674

Comment: And then if the billing tier was say `5` I would do `(5*5)*200/1024/1024`?

Comment: So a full conversion of `1279262720` bytesBilled would be `(5*1)*((1279262720/1024/1024)/1024/1024) = $0.00581741333`?